# How to change the font in the title tag of a site?

Tags: html, page-title

I saw youtube doing this :

[image]

Then I checked the page source and was even more surprised to find special the special font there.

[image]

How do they do such a thing?

Comment: different characters, has nothing to do with styling it.         

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: I found this. https://igfonts.io/
It's very nice to have a fancy font in the ttle, but I imagine it's bad for SEO